# Ajax: Use variable to fetch value of HTML object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can someone help me to convert these lines into one for loop?

```
var optie1 = "";
if($('#form #optie1_check').is(':checked')) {
    optie1 = $('#form #optie1_naam').val();
}
var optie2 = "";
if($('#form #optie2_check').is(':checked')) {
    optie2 = $('#form #optie2_naam').val();
}
```

I can't seem to find my answer on Google, don't really know how to search for it.
I want something like this:

```
for loop (i) {
    var str = "optie" + (i+1) + "_check";
    var str2 = "optie" + (i+1) + "_naam";
    if($('#form #str').is(':checked')) {
        opties = $('#form #str2').val();
    }
}
```

And opties is an array I will be putting all the values in, so I can pass it later on with:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "voegOptiesToe.php",
    data: "opties="+opties,
    ...
}
```

Comment: is it just so you can pass it to a processing script? If so, all you need to do is data: ('#form_id').serialize(), in your ajax request. If it's null or set, it will be passed and you can pick it up in your server side script. You can see the values being passed using firebug or chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use `.serialize()` which encode a set of form elements as a string for submission

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

For example,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "voegOptiesToe.php",
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    ...
}
```

Comment: I will surely check this out, didn't know this was possible.. I'm new to Ajax/Javascript. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var opties = new Array();
for (i=1; i<=2; i++) {
    var str = "optie" + i + "_check";
    var str2 = "optie" + i + "_naam";

    if($('#form #'+str).is(':checked')) {
        opties.push($('#form #'+str2).val());
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/IorgaMihai/tmDpW/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var optie,i=1;    
$('#form #optie'+i+'_check').is(':checked').each(function(){
optie+= $('#form #optie'+i+'_naam').val(); 
i++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the same name for both the checkboxes, by default you can retrieve the value as an array in server side.

Or try this:

```
values = []
$("#form input[type='checkbox']")
.filter(function(i,el){
   return $(el).is(':checked');
 })
.each(function(i, el){
   arr.push($(el).val());
 })
```

And you can send the `values` array to ajax post data.